# React-native-windows installation

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I tried to install react-native-windows. I have some troubleshoot with the command:

npx react-native-windows-init --overwrite

NoLatestReactNativeWindows: Error: No version of react-native-windows@latest found
at getLatestRNWVersion (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData
Local\npm-cache_npx\966c6a96be6f5a32\node_modules\react-native-windows-init\src\Cli.ts:249:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at Object.reactNativeWindowsInit (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\966c6a96be6f5a32\node_modules\react-native-windows-init\src\Cli.ts:533:36) {
type: 'NoLatestReactNativeWindows',
data: undefined
}
Command failed. Re-run the command with --verbose for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Manually specifying the version to use worked for me.

```
> npx react-native-windows-init --overwrite --version=0.71.14
```

See [the Microsoft documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/init-cli) for all argument options.

---

I had also reverted my custom `.npmrc` config proxy & registry options to their defaults, and set `strict-ssl=false`. But that might be unrelated because I was also seeing errors for `SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN`.